# Traffic being routed to wrong pods using nginx-ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

Has anyone has come across a scenario where the traffic intended for a service that comes in via nginx ingress controller accidentally ends up in another service’s pods.

Have checked the selectors, endpoints, ingress config etc., and didn’t get much of a clue.

One other thing we observe is that the source of the request has something to go with it, at least from the looks of it.

For example, if trying to hit the service from local machine, it resolves well and hitting the service from another unix box, it is routed wrongly.

The setup I have is an `EKS cluster 1.23` with `Nginx Ingress Version 4.4.2` (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx) fronted by a AWS NLB and accessed from the outside world via `VPC Service Endpoint`

Anyone else have hit something like this?

TIA

Comment: I've only ever hit this when there was an error in my selectors and labels. This question would be easier to answer with a [mcve] -- can you provide us with a set of deployment manifests that reproduce this problem?

Comment: Check each of the services endpoints and double check that there are no ips that belong to other pods, or share the manifests for all the yamls